# solve arrayoutofboundexception error in java program

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem in my code. When I run my code, the eclipse told me I have arrayoutofboundexception error. But I am not really know how can i solve this for my code. I read several questions related with array out of bound exception error, but could not apply for my code. Here is my code related with problem. thank you. appreciate your help.

```
   char[][] cells;
  int column = 300; 
  int row = 200;
   cells= this.getCells();
   ...
   if(cells[row][column] == '2'){  // error
                // eat the pill
                cells[row][column] = '1';
            }
            else if(cells[row][column] == '3'){
                // eat the power pill
                cells[row][column] = '1';
            }


....

for (int r=0; r<rows; r++) {
            for (int c=0; c<columns; c++) {
                **if (cells[r][c] == '2')** { // error
                    //draw pill
                    g.fillRect(c*STEP-3, r*STEP-3, 6, 6);


                }
                else if (cells[r][c] == '3'){
                    //draw power pill
                    g.fillRect(c*STEP-6, r*STEP-6, 12, 12);

                }
            }
        }


public char[][] getCells()
    {
        char[][] cells = new char[rows][columns];
        for (int  r =0; r < rows; r++){
            System.arraycopy(lines.get(r).toCharArray(), 0, cells[r], 0, columns);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access the index of array that is out of the range for array `cells`

after initilization

```
cells= this.getCells();
```

check the dimension of array, You are trying to access `[200][300]` which causes the issue

Comment: hey, i add the charAt[] getCell method, but i still don't know how to fix this.

Comment: try running your code in debug mode and see the dimension of `cells` array

Comment: cells[row][column]==> row is 194, column is 113, i think they are within the 200 and 300. i am confuse

Comment: they are within 200 and 300, but if you try to access [200][300] they are out of 194, 133 and so the exception

Comment: do you have any idea about how to fix this problem?

Comment: don't access the index that is out of bound, do you know what you are trying to do by `if(cells[row][column] == '2'){`